# MAPIInitialize() returns 0x80004005

Tags: mapi

Hi
I have a windows service I wrote (using C/C++) that uses MAPI and Redemption.dll to convert a mail message from the RFC822 format to the Outlook proprietary format.
It works fine on a certain number of systems, but on a particular box it fails with error 0x80004005 when I call MAPIInitialize(NULL);

I wrote a sample command line application that initialize MAPI in the same way (indeed using the same source code) and it works fine.

I transformed the windows service so that I can call it from the command line (thinking it could be a permission problem), but no way :(

any suggestion?

thanks
stefano

p.s. I found that the error 0x80004005 on MAPIinitialize() is erratic.
I tried to reinstall MAPI support, but no result.

Comment: The only causes I can find for these are (A) CoInitialize has already been called and so MAPIInitialize was already called, don't call it again, and (B) There is no "Extended" MAPI client on the computer.